# Vuejs deferred events on ajax content

Tags: events, vue.js, deferred

I have some vuejs events.

```
 <div @mouseover="activate" @mouseout="deactivate" class="item featured">
```

They work fine but when the content is loaded in via a simple jquery load() it does not trigger. How can I defer these events in vuejs?

edit:

The load is triggered by clicking the nav

```
 <li v-on:click="filterTalents" data-department="hardware">




 filterTalents: function(event) { 
       var dept= $(event.target).closest('li').data('department');
       $( ".content" ).load( "includes/"+dept+".html", function() 

});

       },

       activate: function(event) {
        $(event.target).closest('.item').addClass('active');

       },

        deactivate: function(event) {
        $(event.target).closest('.item').removeClass('active');

       },
```

Comment: Need to see where  jquery `.load()` is used.

Comment: It is in another vuejs method which takes some data off the button and loads it in.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want to add class dynamically to an element, you can use [dynamic class binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) provided by vue.

A simple example would be to pass an object to `v-bind:class` to dynamically toggle classes:

```
<div v-bind:class="{ active: isActive }"></div>
```

The above syntax means the presence of the active class will be determined by the truthiness of the data property isActive.